# Connecting to the database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, windows-7

I use NetBeans to run PHP code.  The code is used to update a database table on our company's server.  So I used the code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('192.168.X.X:X','X','X');
mysql_select_db('X',$link);
if (!$link) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
            echo 'Connected successfully';
            mysql_close($link);
```

but when I click run, this error message is returned:

```
( ! ) Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.140' (10060) in C:\wamp\www\database\index.php on line 9
( ! ) Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\wamp\www\database\index.php on line 10
Call Stack
```

Comment: Is your mysql server configured for remote connetions?

Comment: You're giving away the IP address you were trying to hide in your error output :)

Comment: why have you blanked out an internal IP address, and then also left it in the error message?

Comment: And it is a local/non-routable one...

Comment: i tnk you should give give localhost instead of ip. connecting through ip may be blocked

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

The first error is self-explanatory. PHP can't connect to a database at the given host.  Why this may be will require further investigation on your part (is the SQL server running?  Is it configured to accept non-local connections?  Is there a firewall protecting the port the SQL server is listening to?)

The second error is due to the fact you're not bothering to check whether or not the connect succeeded and just assuming that it did.  If the connection cannot be made then mysql_connect will return false.  You need to check for this before you can be sure that you have a valid open connection.

```
$link = mysql_connect('192.168.X.X:X','X','X');
if (false !== $link)
{
    mysql_select_db('X',$link);
    // Rest of your code goes here
}
```

Incidentally, you should consider the mysql_* functions to be deprecated.  There are far better alternatives such as mysqli or PDO, and you should be using one of those instead. [The manual page on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) makes some suggestions regarding alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

the reasons may be

The MySQL server isn't running.

MySQL's configuration file specifies that it is only listening on a certain IP:Port and that you're not communicating through the specified address

The user name being used to authenticate to the MySQL server is not allowed to connect from the client computer's IP address/host

for more details look at the following link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 0):

you can check your mysql log for detecting the problem .It is hard to tell what exactly the problem .
may be your server is not configured for remote connection through ip. if that's the problem you can use ,provided script is on same server

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','X','X') or die('error connecting to db');
```